# Are the following two maps monomorphisms?

Tags: group-theory, limits-colimits

Let $A_0$, $A_1$ and $A_2$ be three finitely presented groups, together with a diagram $A_1 \xleftarrow{j_1} A_0 \xrightarrow{j_2} A_2$. Let $A$ be the pushforward of the diagram, $f_i: A_i \to A$ the characteristic map and suppose first that $j_i$ is a monomorphism for both $i=1,2$ . It seems like an almost trivial thing to answer, but somehow I cannot wrap my head around the following question:

*Is it true that each $f_i$ is again a monomorphism ?*

I have the following idea, i don't know if it is all sound, and it goes as this:

Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^l$ be a (finite) generating set of $A_0$.
The characteristic map $f_1: A_1 \to A$ is the composition of the inclusion $g_1: A_1 \to A_1 \ast A_2$ and the projection $\pi: A_1 \ast A_2 \to A$, where we divide out the smallest normal subgroup $N \unlhd A_1 \ast A_2$ generated by words of the form $j_1(a_k) \ast j_2(a_k)^{-1}$ for $k=1,..,l$. The fact that $j_2$ is a monomorphism *seems* to already imply that $g_1(A_1) \cap N = \{1\}$. That is since $j_2$ is injective, we get $j_2(a_k) \neq 1$ for each $k$, so each non-trivial word in $N$ must have some letters in $A_2$. Is this true ? Since $g_1$ is trivially injective, so must be $f_1$. By symmetry, we therefore have the following implications:

1) $j_2$ injective $\implies$ $f_1$ injective

2) $j_1$ injective $\implies$ $f_2$ injective.

Is this the right idea to go about ? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your argument that $g(A_1) \cap = \{1\}$ is not a formal proof. When $j_1$ and $j_2$ are both monomorphisms, you can think of them as embeddings, and so you are trying to prove the result that $A_1$ and $A_2$ embed into the amalgamated free product $A_1 *_{A_0} A_2$. This is true, but the proof is nontrivial.Assuming that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are finitely generated/presented does not help much. There is a technical algebraic proof that uses a normal form for group elements using coset representatives of $A_0$ in $A_1$ and $A_2$. There are also topological proofs.

Comment: I think the answer to [this question] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601463/a-monomorphism-of-groups-which-is-not-universal?rq=1) shows that the injectivity of $j_2$ is insufficient to conclude that $f_1$ also has to be injective. I would be really interested in a reference to this highly non-trivial proof you were talking about

Comment: Related to Derek Holt's comment: A good book on this subject (and in my opinion a must-read) is *Serre's Trees*. On the first pages of this book their is a proof for this fact (and as Derek Holt pointed out, no assumptions on finitely presentations) with the help of a *normal form*.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is highly appreciated!

Comment: @BerniWaterman: Btw (concerning your link), if you don't assume injectivity for both maps $j_1, j_2$ kind of "everything" can happen. E.g. If you take $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow PSL(2, \mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ then the corresponding amalgam is trivial!

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I am not really very experienced in group theory, so "simple" counterexamples like these do not immediately come to my mind. In my mind, the simplest groups are the finitely generated abelian ones, so naturally, I would first always try to look for a counterexample only using those kinds of groups.